# how  to  make  edit  and  delete  button in details view control  visible  based on user  role

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I am using a `DetailsView` control.  Here I have both edit and delete  buttons.

I am using `autogenerateitbutton="true" autogeneratedeletebuton="true"`

I have two user roles: admin and normal user.

In a database, I have a table with a column storing the user role ID (1 for admin, 2 for normal user).

If the role  type is admin (1) then I want to show  both the edit and the delete buttons.
If the role type is mormal (2) then I don't want to show these two buttons.
How can I do this in a `DetailsView` control?

How  can I  get these  controlID (i.e edit and  delete  button)  in  `.cs`  file? Based  on that I need  to  show the  edit and delete buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method called [DetailsView.ChangeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.changemode.aspx) that Switches the DetailsView control to the specified mode i.e Edit or Delete or ReadOnly.

```
void Page_Load()  
    {
      if (IsPostBack == false)
      {
         if (roleid==1)
          {
           detailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
          }
          else
          {
           detailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
          }
      }

     }
```

Comment: 4 years later and you helped me.